# Prometheus/Micrometer | http_server_requests_seconds_bucket is not shown

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

There are two springboot2.3 services using micrometer and expose metrics to prometheus.
Their metric configs are the same, and both have this line

`management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram.http.server.requests=true`

but only one service exposed this metric `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` successfully while the other one didn't.
For other metrics like `http_server_requests_seconds_count` (summary type), `http_server_requests_duration_ms_bucket`(histogram type) are working fine.

What is the possible reason for missing `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket`?

Will it be shown only after a certain amount of calls? some other histogram type metrics are shown, but no this line
`#TYPE http_server_requests_seconds histogram`

Answer (score 0):

The things I can think of are:

1. One of them is not a Spring Boot 3 app and the property name is different.
2. Something overrides the property value.
3. You have a `MeterFilter` that changes the value of the `DistributionConfig`.
4. Something else other than Spring Boot produces that output so the Spring Boot property has no effect. Do you use any Java agents or any other metric SDKs?